# jQuery: Multiclick breaks animation

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, animation

I have a simple form:

```
<form id="form" action="file.php" method="POST">

  <input class="form-control" type="number"  name="p"  value="0">
  <label for="p">Text</label>

  <input class="form-control" type="number"  name="b"  value="0">
  <label for="b">Text 2</label>

  <input id="submit" type="submit" name="save" value="Save" tabindex="10"/>

  <div id="msg" class="alert-success" style="visibility: hidden;">Saved.</div>

</form>
```

After User submits this form (may submit unlimited times), he gets a success message, which will slowly fade out.

jQuery:

```
   $(document).ready()
    {
        $("#form").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let url = $(this).attr("action");
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#form').serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    $('#msg').css({opacity: 1.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 0}, 1500);
                },
                error: function () {
                    $('#error-msg').css({opacity: 1.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 0}, 1500);
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

I've used animate, because in this case other elements in Layout will not jump upwards, after message div is faded.

but the problem is, when user clicks couple of times too fast (as long as message is still fading out), the success message will not be displayed anymore in the future as he clicks. To get this message displayed once more, the page has to be refreshed.

Unfortunatelly, I could not make the code working on jsfiddle, because I get error:  `{"error":"key missing: title"}` (but this is not the issue of my question)

The question is: how to fix this bug with disappeared success message, if the user clicks many times as long as fading is in process?

UPDATE:

so, thanks to @Kishan the issue is solved. Added ID to the submit button and in AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        beforeSend : function(){
            $("#submit").prop('disabled',true);
        },
        success: function () {
            $('#msg').css({opacity: 1.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 0}, 1500);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#submit").prop('disabled',false);
            },1500);
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#error-msg').css({opacity: 1.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 0}, 1500);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#submit").prop('disabled',false);
            },1500);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Make your submit button disabled until your ajax call is submit and message will be displayed.

Comment: nice trick! Can there be a plan b in this issue?

Comment: Second plan is that you can check that is message div is exists in DOM, if no then  display message and if yes then not append message to DOM.

Comment: BTW, how would I refactor the code to make the button disabled only till the message is faded?

Comment: put $("#msg").prop('disabled',true); before start of ajax call and in success of ajax $('#msg').css({opacity: 1.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 0}, 1500); setTimeOut(function(){$("#msg").prop('disabled',false);},1500)

Comment: hm, didn't work... ((
I also modified your code like this:  success: function () {
                        $('#msg').css({opacity: 1.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 0}, 1500);
                        setTimeOut(function () {
                            $("#submit").attr('disabled', true);
                        }, 1500)
                    }   I've added id to a submitt button. Didn't work also (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Check this one.

```js
$(document).ready()
{
    $("#form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let url = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            beforeSend : function(){
                $("#msg").prop('disabled',true);
            },
            success: function () {
                $('#msg').css({opacity: 1.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 0}, 1500);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#msg").prop('disabled',false);
                },1500);
            },
            error: function () {
                $('#error-msg').css({opacity: 1.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 0}, 1500);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $("#msg").prop('disabled',false);
                },1500);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: setTimeOut is not defined`

Comment: I have changed answer please check it again.It is just setTimeOut to setTimeout.